# What container orchestration tools can deploy containers with routable IP addresses?

Tags: docker, consul, orchestration, docker-network

I am trying to deploy containers onto a distributed system of several nodes, with the end goal of having each container be bound to its own specific routable IP address. This is due to the fact that I want to use hardware load balancers for my docker containers, which require individual IP addresses.

I can achieve containers with routable IP addresses by using the docker command line tool to launch containers running on servers with multiple network interfaces (eth0:0. eth0:1, eth0:2, eth1, eth2, eth3, ect...) each of which have their own routable IP addresses.  Each container can then attach itself to an available IP address of one of the interfaces using a specific `-p` option.

For example if I had an IP of `1.2.3.4` on `eth0:2` that I wanted to attach an nginx container to I could attach it with the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 1.2.3.4:80:80 nginx
```

The limitation of this is that there is a specific pool of routable IP addresses for each instance running docker.  My orchestration tool must be able to only use IP addresses from that pool and only use each IP address once.  (Don't worry about scaling issues of this, more IP addresses can always be added from an openstack management node).

Up until now I have tried to achieve this with docker swarm 1.12, using docker services, but it is very clear that this is not the intended use case for that orchestration tool.

So I am looking for a new orchestration tool that will let me do the following:

1. Bind docker containers on multiple servers to specific IP addresses, defined when the docker container is created.
2. Know that each server has a specific pool of IP addresses it can choose from and know that the pool will be different on every node.
3. Will not override itself and attempt to bind two running containers to the same IP address.

It must also provide some of the more common aspects of container orchistration tools such as:

4. Provide automatic container rescheduling on the event of node failure.
5. Provide self healing, where new containers are created to replace old containers that have died.
6. Provide a simple system for container deployment.

I should also note that each of my servers are also part of a consul cluster.  To me, based on my very specific networking requirements, it seems as if the best solution is to manage the whole system with a combination of consul watches, consul health checks and consul key values (with the possible use of the older containerized version of docker swarm) that run personally written scripts on each instance running docker to determine the right course of actions any one server should take.

However I would rather use a common container orchestration tool for my purposes.  So I would like to know if any of the other container orchestration tools (such as mesos, kubernetes, nomad, ect) allow this level of docker port mapping customization?  Or am I better off just using custom consul health checks and watches?

Also note that I am running my system in a private openstack cloud, on ubuntu 14.04 servers (so fleet is not an option).

Comment: This could be a great question for the [DevOps proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops?referrer=Ih4MeFhuukv7h376hrOevQ2) as you are trying to solve a concrete deployment problem.

Comment: Ok sure, I've flagged the post to be moved.

Comment: The DevOps site is “only” at the proposal stage, so you cannot move the post there, but maybe you can add your question title and link to this question in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Check **Docker Swarm**:

https://docs.docker.com/swarm/

or **Kubernetes**

http://kubernetes.io/docs/

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer. You are not answering my question, to do that you need to tell me **WHY** either of your suggestions will fulfill my requirements.  No docker swarm is not an option, as I stated in my explanation.  Furthermore, yes I am aware kubernetes exists, the question is if it (or any other common tool) can fulfill my specific port mapping requirements.

Comment: I dont know much about Kubernetes scheduling strategies, but as far as I know in Docker Swarm the only supports these values:
spread,binpack,random. 
Spread and binpack strategies are based on node's available CPU, RAM, number of containers it has. 
Random strategy uses no computation, it select node at random
so I dont think you can deploy on a specific IP address